# DNN Count User Query

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, dotnetnuke

Why is DNN running this query continously:

```
Select count(*) 
from dbo.DNN_vw_users 
where portalID = @PortalID and IsDeleted = 0
```

This query is taking a total CPU time of over 600,000ms and its still increasing.

```
USE [gssdb]
```

GO

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[DNN_vw_Users]  

AS
SELECT     
    U.UserID, 
    UP.PortalId, 
    U.Username, 
    U.FirstName, 
    U.LastName, 
    U.DisplayName, 
    U.IsSuperUser, 
    U.Email, 
    U.AffiliateId, 
    U.UpdatePassword, 
    UP.Authorised, 
            (CASE WHEN UP.PortalId IS NULL THEN U.IsDeleted ELSE UP.IsDeleted END) AS IsDeleted, 
    UP.RefreshRoles, 
    U.LastIPAddress,
    U.CreatedByUserID, 
    U.CreatedOnDate, 
    U.LastModifiedByUserID, 
    U.LastModifiedOnDate
FROM dbo.DNN_Users AS U 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.DNN_UserPortals AS UP ON U.UserID = UP.UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `SELECT` directly (from table) -

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM dbo.DNN_tbl_users
WHERE portalID = @PortalID
    AND IsDeleted = 0
```

*Update2:*

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM dbo.DNN_Users U --WITH(NOWAIT)
WHERE U.IsDeleted = 0
    AND U.UserID IN (
        SELECT UP.UserID
        FROM dbo.DNN_UserPortals UP --WITH(NOWAIT)
        WHERE UP.portalID = @PortalID
            AND UP.IsDeleted = 0
    )
```

*Update 3:*

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM dbo.DNN_Users U --WITH(NOWAIT)
JOIN (
    SELECT UP.UserID
    FROM dbo.DNN_UserPortals UP --WITH(NOWAIT)
    WHERE UP.portalID = @PortalID
        AND UP.IsDeleted = 0
) UP ON U.UserID = UP.UserID
```

Comment: I need to know why DNN is doing this continuosly, if I could just stop or delete the proc

Comment: Please provide DDL for `dbo.DNN_vw_users`.

Comment: Just edited my question with the DDL, the total CPU is now over 800K

Comment: `Database Explorer -> Views -> DNN_vw_Users -> Popup-menu -> Script view as -> ALTER`

Answer (score 0):

What DEVART suggested is right... try to count on the basis of a column instead of all columns as its would take way longer to get the count if may be your columns list contain for eg. an "image" column.

Note-

If the above is not the case,I would like to suggest that if it is something like you are unit testing on something for whatever purpose, then you temporarily remove the transaction if any on the view or table so that the count query gives you finite time as it will be out of transaction. But make sure that when i mentioned unit testing i suppose you are not on production database/environment as that would have disastrous effects to remove transactions in that environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using the Users Online feature of DNN, you can disable that in the Host Settings. I imagine that is likely what is causing the count to continuously run.

Comment: I am not using the Users online module, what do I disable to prevent this query from running continously

Comment: You aren't using the Module, or you don't have Users Online enabled in the host settings?